# z-index not working properly in html

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have an html page with a z indexed dropdown menu. I have this dropdown menu positioned absolutely.
with some given left and top values. The problem is the dropdown menu is at its place when the window is full screen but when the window is changed in size ( made lesser than the pc window the z indexed element shifts in position which makes it look awkward. I know it is due to absolute positioning.

can anybody please tell me how to fix this ? how to make the dropdown stay always in place. attached is the image.
                          [image: dropdown]

Comment: I think you will need to give us more information. The fix could depend on how your other elements are positioned.

Comment: first of all resizing your window don't changes anything on your z-index. For the positioning you will need to use javascript and set the position in the resize event.

Comment: @sven Bieder: So, i should first calculate the current window size and then change the positioning. Is that right? can relative positioning with respect to the date box in the image above help ?

Comment: @Preli: Its been answered already. I knew relative positioning could solve it but how id couldn't work out.

Comment: @limelights I would have accepted the answers if i knew how to do that. I read one of the articles that said click the check mark but there was no check mark anywhere. i mentioned that in one of my earlier posts also when a person asked me to accept the answer. It is now that i can see it and hence checked it wherever possible. by the way what's with the vote down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the containing element has 'position: relative;' set on it, the top / left values are based on the first containing element with a position set. If the containing element does not have a position set, it will try the next parent, and so on until it finally defaults to the body.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/erinfreeman/AHWS2/

div with the id of 'one' has position relative, so the child div bases its bottom / right co-ordinates from that. the div with id of 'two' doesn't have position set so the child div goes to the next parent

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working and i understand now why it should work this way.Thanks again.